# If complex $z$ satisfies $z+\frac{1}{z}=\cos x$, then evaluate $z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$ for integer $n$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Let $z$ be a complex number such that
> $$
> z + \frac{1}{z} = \cos x
> $$
> Then what is the value of the expression
> $$
> z^n + \frac{1}{z^n}
> $$
> where $n$ is an integer?

Please help me. I have tried somehow using the trigonometric way of defining complex numbers but still didn't manage to get anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by $z+\frac{1}{z}=\cos(x)?$

Comment: Is $z=x+iy$ and the $x$ in $\cos(x)$ refers to that??

Comment: z+1/z = cos(x) it's a relation that needs to help us to get to the other answer.

Comment: so what is $x$? How is it related to $z$?

Comment: x is a constant that we suppose to know it.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be real?

Comment: You know, this would be a whole lot nicer if that were $z+\frac1z=2\cos x$...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $$z = \cos x + i \sin x$$ and $$\dfrac {1}{z} = \cos x - i \sin x$$

Then by DeMoivre's theorem $$z^n = (\cos x + i \sin x)^n = \cos nx + i \sin nx$$ $$\dfrac {1}{z^n} = (\cos x - i \sin x)^n = \cos nx - i \sin nx$$

What do you need to get $z^n + \dfrac {1}{z^n}?$

Comment: Here $z+\frac 1z=2\cos x$ but OP said $z+\frac 1 z=\cos x$

Comment: I just read jmerry's comment above...I would think the sentiment would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{cases}
z+\frac1z=\cos x\\
z\cdot\frac1z=1
\end{cases}
Considering $t^2-\cos x\cdot t+1=0$, and we get
\begin{equation}
\{z,\frac1z\}=\{\frac{\cos x+\sqrt{\cos^2x-4}}{2},\frac{\cos x-\sqrt{\cos^2x-4}}{2}\}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{align}
z^n+\frac{1}{z^n} 
&= (\frac{\cos x+\sqrt{\cos^2x-4}}{2})^n+(\frac{\cos x-\sqrt{\cos^2x-4}}{2})^n\\
&= \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}\cos^{n-2k}x\cdot(\cos^2x-4)^k}{2^n}.
\end{align}
not so beautiful :(